# Custom widget not displaying on stage server

Tags: magento-1.9, widget

I have created a custom widget, which is shown on local but when I pushed to staging, its not showing. Why?

Comment: To avoid closing and down votes, please explain your problem better and what you need ! i remove you this down vote !